# regarding node-nlp how to manually add value

Tags: nlp, classification, nlp.js

In nlpManger we can addDocument as the following

```
manager.addDocument('en', 'I saw %hero% eating %food%', 'sawhero');
```

how can I manually add the value to it so that I have more control over the final classification score ?